# Limitation when working with large sql views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am looking at ways to scale up a small project I am working on. At present I have a suite of reports on SSRS written off of a number of stored procedures using one sql view. At the moment this view is populated from data obtained from 3 databases.

At the moment this approach works well, with the view containing approximately 50,000 rows of data. To scale my test project up, the view will likely end up containing 1.5-2 million rows and queried by many users via SSRS.

Could anybody give me any pointers on where I should be directing my time to learn how to accomplish this task in a more efficient/advanced way?

I appreciate this is an expansive question, so even some "read up on this" type answers would be a huge help.

Many thanks for taking the time to read this.

Chris

Comment: Unless it's an **Indexed View**, it doesn't *contain* any data at all. Views are just stored statements.....

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Are you asking for a strategy to create test data?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, sorry my question is not clear. Just looking for pointers on how to scale a small project and improve my limited knowledge. I appreciate a view doesn't contain data, I have just read that they are not efficient when they reference large data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing aggregation of many data sources. There comes a point where you may instead want to develop an ETL solution to refresh your aggregated data into a central repository. From a maintenance perspective, this means more moving parts to tend to, but it also means the end user doesn't see a single source's database going offline for maintenance (barring noticing old data). This also allows you to present a maintenance plan specific to the data you're aggregating. Migrating data to your server opens options for use beyond your current scope as well.

In general, though, read up on data warehousing and ETL strategies.

Comment: Thanks for the response, having done some further research an ETL solution looks like what I need.